# A useful criterion in dispersive PDE.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I would like to prove the following theorem:
Consider two Banach spaces $X\hookrightarrow Y$ and $1<p,q\leq\infty$. Let $(f_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a bounded sequence in $L^q(I,Y)$ and let $f:I\mapsto Y$ be such that $f_{n}(t)\rightharpoonup f(t)$ in $Y$ for a.a. $t\in I$. If $f_n$ is bounded in $L^p(I,X)$ and if $X$ is  reflexive, then $f\in L^p(I,X)$ and $\|f\|_{L^p(I,X)}\leq\liminf_{n\rightarrow}\|f_n\|_{L^p(I,X)}$.

I don't have any references.

Comment: The role of $q$ is unclear. It only appears when you say $f_n$ are bounded in $L^q$. But then they are also assumed to be bounded in $L^p$. And nothing prevents $q$ from being equal to $p$. So, what is $q$ for?

Comment: I think you must have that exists $q$ such that $f_n$ in boundend in $L^q(I,Y)$ otherwise it will be false. Pay attention that $X$ and $Y$ are not the same space.